# How to record game scene in spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I have a project with SpriteKit. I have seen the video of WWDC15 for ReplayKit. 
I added ReplayKit to my project and i want record my GameScene and share it in Facebook , save in camera roll more...and more.

anything not working now but i added the functions and i organized all.

thanks!

**Start Record**

```
func startScreenRecording() {
    // Do nothing if screen recording hasn't been enabled.

    let sharedRecorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder()

    // Register as the recorder's delegate to handle errors.
    sharedRecorder.delegate = self

    sharedRecorder.startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled(true) { error in
        if let error = error {
            self.showScreenRecordingAlert(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

**Stop Record**

```
func stopScreenRecordingWithHandler(handler:(() -> Void)) {
    let sharedRecorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder()

    sharedRecorder.stopRecordingWithHandler { (previewViewController: RPPreviewViewController?, error: NSError?) in
        if let error = error {
            // If an error has occurred, display an alert to the user.
            self.showScreenRecordingAlert(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if let previewViewController = previewViewController {
            // Set delegate to handle view controller dismissal.
            previewViewController.previewControllerDelegate = self

            /*
            Keep a reference to the `previewViewController` to
            present when the user presses on preview button.
            */
            self.presentViewController(previewViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        handler()
    }
}
```

**Other Functions of ReplayKit**

```
  func showScreenRecordingAlert(message: String) {
        // Pause the scene and un-pause after the alert returns.

        GameScene().paused = true

        // Show an alert notifying the user that there was an issue with starting or stopping the recorder.
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "ReplayKit Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)

        let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { _ in

            GameScene().paused = false
        }
        alertController.addAction(alertAction)

        /*
        `ReplayKit` event handlers may be called on a background queue. Ensure
        this alert is presented on the main queue.
        */
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.view?.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func discardRecording() {
        // When we no longer need the `previewViewController`, tell `ReplayKit` to discard the recording and nil out our reference
        RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder().discardRecordingWithHandler {
            self.previewViewController = nil
        }
    }

    // MARK: RPScreenRecorderDelegate

    func screenRecorder(screenRecorder: RPScreenRecorder, didStopRecordingWithError error: NSError, previewViewController: RPPreviewViewController?) {
        // Display the error the user to alert them that the recording failed.
        showScreenRecordingAlert(error.localizedDescription)

        /// Hold onto a reference of the `previewViewController` if not nil.
        if previewViewController != nil {
            self.previewViewController = previewViewController
        }
    }

    // MARK: RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate

    func previewControllerDidFinish(previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
        previewViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

**Game Scene**

```
import SpriteKit
import ReplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate{

func addRecordButton() {

RecordButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Record-Off.png")
RecordButton.name = "RecordButton"
RecordButton.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2 + 185, y: self.size.height/2 + 285)
RecordButton.size = CGSizeMake(32,32)
addChild(RecordButton)

}

func Record() {
let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder()
if recorder.available{
RecordButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Record-On.png")
print("Record")
} else {
RecordButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Record-Off.png")
print("Stop Record")
}
  }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

                 for touch in touches {
                 let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

                    if {
                    if (RecordButton.containsPoint(location)){
                            Record()
                        }
                }

            }
```

Comment: I am not completely familiar with RPK, but [Apple's API documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ReplayKit/Reference/RPScreenRecorder_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/RPScreenRecorder/startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled:handler:) are probably worth reading as well.  It says that you call the start method, then when done, call the end method, it will pop up a window for the user to trim/cut the movie, and _share_.  And also to implement the delegate of it as well.

Comment: My code must to work??

Comment: The delegate?  Maybe.  Again, I'm not too familiar with this.  You will probably want to be able to catch any errors that it sends to its delegate, but maybe you don't need them to get basic testing...

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, RPScreenRecorderDelegate, RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var startRecordingButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var stopRecordingButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityView: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    private let recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder()


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if SIMULATOR {
            NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.showSimulatorWarning), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            return
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        recorder.delegate = self
        activityView.hidden = true
        buttonEnabledControl(recorder.recording)
    }

    @IBAction func startRecordingAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        activityView.hidden = false

        // start recording
        recorder.startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled(true) { [unowned self] (error) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                [unowned self] in
                self.activityView.hidden = true
            }

            if let error = error {
                print("Failed start recording: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            print("Start recording")
            self.buttonEnabledControl(true)


        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopRecordingAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        activityView.hidden = false

        //end recording
        recorder.stopRecordingWithHandler({ [unowned self] (previewViewController, error) in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.activityView.hidden = true
            }

            self.buttonEnabledControl(false)

            if let error = error {
                print("Failed stop recording: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            print("Stop recording")
            previewViewController?.previewControllerDelegate = self



            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { [unowned self] in
                // show preview vindow
                self.presentViewController(previewViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
    }

    //MARK: - Helper
    //control the enabled each button
    private func buttonEnabledControl(isRecording: Bool) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
            [unowned self] in

            let enabledColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 122.0/255.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
            let disabledColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()

            if !self.recorder.available {
                self.startRecordingButton.enabled = false
                self.startRecordingButton.backgroundColor = disabledColor
                self.stopRecordingButton.enabled = false
                self.stopRecordingButton.backgroundColor = disabledColor

                return
            }

            self.startRecordingButton.enabled = !isRecording
            self.startRecordingButton.backgroundColor = isRecording ? disabledColor : enabledColor
            self.stopRecordingButton.enabled = isRecording
            self.stopRecordingButton.backgroundColor = isRecording ? enabledColor : disabledColor
        }
    }


    func showSimulatorWarning() {
        let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
//        let actionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "ReplayKit不支持模拟器", message: "请使用真机运行这个Demo工程", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(actionOK)
//        alert.addAction(actionCancel)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func showSystemVersionWarning() {
        let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "系统版本需要是iOS9.0及以上才支持ReplayKit", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(actionOK)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }



    // MARK: - RPScreenRecorderDelegate
    // called after stopping the recording
    func screenRecorder(screenRecorder: RPScreenRecorder, didStopRecordingWithError error: NSError, previewViewController: RPPreviewViewController?) {
        print("Stop Recording ...\n");
    }

    // called when the recorder availability has changed
    func screenRecorderDidChangeAvailability(screenRecorder: RPScreenRecorder) {
        let availability = screenRecorder.available
        print("Availability: \(availability)\n");
    }

    // MARK: - RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate
    // called when preview is finished
    func previewControllerDidFinish(previewController: RPPreviewViewController) {
        print("Preview finish");

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { 
            [unowned previewController] in
            // close preview window
            previewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```